# extending model : Access parent attribute from the child

Tags: eloquent, octobercms

have to accessing parent attribute from child

after instanciate objectTwo, `$object_two->some_objectone_field` get null value instead of expected value

below both objects structure :

object one

```
<?php namespace Username\Plugin\Models;
use Model;
class ObjectOne extends Model
{
    use \October\Rain\Database\Traits\Validation;
    public $rules = [
     ....   
    ];

    public $table = 'username_plugin_objectone';

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

}
```

object two

```
<?php namespace Username\Plugin\Models;

use Username\Plugin\Models\ObjectOne;

class ObjectTwo extends ObjectOne
{

    public $rules = [
     ....
    ];

    public $table = 'username_plugin_objecttwo';

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

}
```

database tables

```
username_plugin_objectone table :
id
some_objectone_field
...

username_plugin_objecttwo table:
id
objectone_id
some_objecttwo_field
...
```

what am i going wrong ? thanks by advance

Answer (score 0):

ok, things are more clear, i can't access parent properties from database because the parent $table property is overload by child $table property ...